# Proof of the Beltrami theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I'm studying from a textbook and came across a theorem as the following, which it calls the Beltrami Theorem:

> **Beltrami Theorem:**  A Riemannian metric $g$ is projectively flat if and only if it is of constant sectional curvature.

the only book I study in this regard is:

"Riemannian geometry" by do Carmo

I'm trying to find more information and/or a proof of it that is fully understandable for me. Is it also satisfied  for the Finsler manifolds? Is anyone more knowledgeable of this theorem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://library.msri.org/books/Book50/files/06BR.pdf  ... may be useful

Comment: [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2508v1.pdf) on page 34, Theorem 10.6 may also be useful.